# plotting a very asymmetric "pixel matrix" with R

Tags: r

All the examples i find that use plot.im or similar, use matrices that are squared or almost squared. I am trying to plot pixel matrices with unusual sizes, for example 18x3000. My problem is that since the x/y ratio is so small, i only see a line in my plots. Is there any way to 'scale' the Y side of the image?

here is an example http://ubuntuone.com/0WchsKI5hd8YEqtTe7xAno

Thanks!

Comment: If you want to scale Y, why not simply duplicate each row in the matrix 20x times?

Comment: Did you try using the `png` function? (or other similar ones, see `?png`). That way you can set the width and height of the output file beforehand...

Comment: @ArthurWulfWhite yes i could do that but was looking for a way to do it in a graphical parameter/function

Comment: @Juan i would like to keep the image size constant, scaling only the contents...

Comment: If you use the `base::image` function instead of `spatstat::plot.im` the matrix will fill the entire plot area. You have to manually fix the colors and such though (the standard palette isn't good for almost anything), but that's not too hard.

Comment: Maybe `ylim`? just a quick guess...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not too familiar with the `im` objects of `spatstat`, but guess from the reference manual that either of these should work (where `x` is your `im` object).

```
# Specify colors
jet.colors <- colorRampPalette(c("#00007F", "blue", "#007FFF", "cyan",
                      "#7FFF7F", "yellow", "#FF7F00", "red", "#7F0000"))(40)
# Using base R
# Note that you might need to transpose `x` to get the orientation right
image(t(as.matrix(x)), col=jet.colors)

# Using lattice
library(lattice)
levelplot(as.matrix(x), aspect="fill", cuts=39, col.regions=jet.colors)
```

Comment: You are absolutely correct...
Turns out if i mess up with par() first, i get what i posted. Not sure why it changes so radically but will have a look. Thanks for help!